# Checking if date matches recurring date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, momentjs

I have a `date` variable containing a date, and an `interval` variable containing an array of numbers. Each number on the `interval` array represents a date, which is acquired by adding said number to the day count of the previous date. For example:

If `date` is equal to `2016-09-01` and `interval` is equal to `[15, 15, 20]`, the resulting dates would be `2016-09-16`, `2016-10-01`, `2016-10-21`, `2016-11-06` and so on.

I want to check if a given date matches that pattern. To do this, I tried using [moment-recur](https://github.com/c-trimm/moment-recur), which does exactly what I want with the `.every()` function, but intervals with repeating numbers don't seem to work (`[15, 15, 20]` would be parsed as `[15, 20`] for example). How can I accomplish this, either with moment-recur or a different library?

Here's the desired output using moment-recur:

```
const now = moment();
const date = moment("2016-09-10", "YYYY-MM-DD");

console.log(date.recur().every([18, 18, 57]).days().matches(now));
```

Comment: Even without dropped repetition, I don't think `every` does what you want. It doesn't match *accumulative* days. For example [15, 20] matches every 15th and every 20th (15, 20, 30, 40), but not 15, then 35, then 50, etc. Is the accumulative match really what you are after?

Comment: As Mark_M says, `[15,15,20]` isn't 15 days, then 15 days, then 20 days. It's every 15 days *and* every 20 days from the start, so starting from 2016-09-01 you'd get 2016-09-16, 2016-09-21, 2016-10-01, 2016-10-11, 2016-10-16, etc. So the `[15, 15]` just specifies the 15 day interval twice.

Comment: Looking at [*the source*](https://github.com/c-trimm/moment-recur/blob/master/moment-recur.js) for *.every* (line 340), the input array is converted to an object using the array values as property names. So repeated values are effectively ignored. What you are specifying is a sequence, so maybe you need a new method for that.

Comment: Ah, @Mark_M is correct. The behavior of `.every()` doesn't seem to be what I want, now that I take a second look at it. I need an accumulative match, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accumulative nature of what you are trying to do is a little tricky.

There may be a nicer way, but I think this works pretty well so long as your interval list isn't too big.

The main insight is that if you are looking for an accumulative interval of say `[2, 10, 11]` then you will be looking for every 2, 12, 23, 25, 35, 46, etc. This amount to looking for three different dates at regular intervals of the sum of your accumulator -- in this case 23. So you could just use moment's `every()` with each of the three cases and a single interval.

For example if you have:

```
const now = moment();
const date = moment("2016-10-22", "YYYY-MM-DD");
const interval = [18, 18, 57]

// sum of the intervals -- i.e. the main interval (93)
const main_int = interval.reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr );

// an array of days for each small interval
const dates = interval.map(i  => moment(date.add(i ,'days')))

// moment mutates the original so this results in 
// [ moment("2016-11-09T00:00:00.000"),
//   moment("2016-11-27T00:00:00.000"),
//   moment("2017-01-23T00:00:00.000") ]

// Now see if any of these days matches the main interval

const match = dates.some(d => d.recur().every(main_int).days().matches(now))
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I needed, yes. The only difference is I forgot to mention I'll need to loop through the array of intervals indefinitely, as they're a recurrent thing, however that should be pretty easy to achieve after your answer. Thank you o/

Comment: But that doesn't repeat the sequence (though not sure if that's required).

Comment: Hey @RobG - Obviously, I could be wrong here, but I think that's what `every(main_int)` does. It should check whether any of the dates in the array match the `recur().every()` which does repeat the sequence.

Comment: Fair enough, it's an interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

In a very kludgy way, what you're trying to do is generate new dates that accumulate according to your sequence, then see if at some point it matches a test date.

The following uses moment.js, but really doesn't need it. The moment functionality could be replaced with about 10 lines of code in a couple of separate functions.

```js
/* @param {Date} sequenceStart - start of sequence
** @param {Array} sequence - sequence of intervals
** @param {Date} date - date for comparison
*/
function inSequence(sequenceStart, sequence, date) {
  // Copy start date so don't affect original
  var s = moment(sequenceStart);
  // Get test date in suitable format
  var d = moment(date).format('YYYYMMDD');
  var i = 0;

  do {
    // debug
    console.log(s.format('YYYYMMDD') + ' ' + d)

    // If dates match, return true
    if (s.format('YYYYMMDD') == d) {
      return true;
    }
    // If didn't match, add the next value in the sequence
    s.add(sequence[i++ % sequence.length], 'day');

  // Stop if go past test date
  } while (s.format('YYYYMMDD') <= d)

  // If didn't return true, return false
  return false;
}

var sequence = [15,15,20];
var start = new Date(2017,8,1); // 1 Sep 2017
var test  = new Date(2017,10,5) // 5 Nov 2017

console.log(inSequence(start, sequence, test));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without having to use `moment-recur` if you want to, using a similar approach to what @Mark_M described

The first step is to determine the number of days between the given date and the start date: `moment(endDate).diff(startDate, 'days');`.

Then, create an array of cumulative totals for the days since start date for each of the entries in the interval array:

```
function sumSoFar(nums) {
   return nums.reduce((sums, num) => {
       const prevSum = last(sums) || 0;
       return sums.concat(num + prevSum);
   }, []);
}

// ...

const sums = sumSoFar(interval);
```

Finally, the sum of the whole interval array is just the last entry in that list, and so we can find out which entry in the interval list it matches by taking the days difference modulo interval sum. If that is `0`, or an entry in the `sums` array, then the date matches the interval. If not, then it doesn't.

Here is the complete code I came up with:

```js
const startDate = moment('2016-09-01');
const interval = [15, 15, 20];
const last = (arr) => arr[arr.length - 1];
const sum = (nums) => nums.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0);

function sumSoFar(nums) {
  return nums.reduce((sums, num) => {
    const prevSum = last(sums) || 0;
    return sums.concat(num + prevSum);
  }, []);
}

const validDates = [moment('2016-09-16'), moment('2016-10-01'), moment('2016-10-21'), moment('2016-11-05')];

function isValid(startDate, interval, date) {
  const days = moment(date).diff(startDate, 'days');
  const sums = sumSoFar(interval);
  const remainingDays = days % last(sums);
  return remainingDays === 0 || sums.indexOf(remainingDays) >= 0;
}

validDates.forEach(d => console.log(isValid(startDate, interval, d)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```